# Cambiar escala eje Y en matplolib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Buen día, estoy haciendo un programa para hallar [Cargas distribuidas en vigas](http://cv.udl.cat/cursos/101606gea/continguts/modul1_nou/tema5.htm#:%7E:text=Cuando%20la%20carga%20por%20unidad,con%20una%20determinada%20secci%C3%B3n%20transversal.) pero aplicando una `función matematica`, lo que quiero que haga mi script es que dada una `función` en un intervalo `[a,b)` esta se grafique en dicho intervalo pero **apoyada** en la viga; hasta allí no tengo problema, el problema surge a la hora de graficar una función cuadratica (x**2) en un intervalo de [0,10) esta tomara grandes valores para el eje y y en cuestión de escalas se veria poco estetico, entonces lo que busco es hacer proporcional la escala del `eje x` con la del `eje y` a continuación dejo unas imagenes de la salida que obtengo, la salida que espero y mi código.

### Figura obtenida

[image: Figura obtenida]

### Figura deseada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Viga donde se tiene que apoyar la función

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Código:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches


class CargasV():
    
    def diseño_viga_apoyada(self,ax):
        """"
        Esta funcion es la encargada de graficar la viga apoyada en el eje x
        inicialmente la longitud de la viga será de 18 metros, este paramtro 
        se puede modificar en la funcion pasandole un valor numerico
        """
        coordenada_y = 0
        coordenada_x = 0
        vertices = [(coordenada_x,coordenada_y),5,-0.25]
        self.vC = vertices #vertices cuadrado
        ax.add_patch(
            patches.Rectangle(
            self.vC[0],
            self.vC[1],
            self.vC[2],
            fill=False,
            label='viga apoyada',
            color=("black"),
            linewidth=1.8
             ))
        return plt.plot()
    
# -/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-    
    def funciones(self,valor_final_x):

        X = np.linspace(0,valor_final_x,1000) #Le doy un valor de 100o por si es una función con muchas curvas como sen(x)
        Y = X**2
        return plt.plot(X,Y)
            
    def plot(self):
 # -/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/- #Caractericticas inciales del plot -/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-    
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.axis('equal')
        ax.grid(ls='--', lw=0.6)
        self.diseño_viga_apoyada(ax)
        self.funciones(5)
        plt.yticks(np.arange(0,25,5))
        plt.title("Cargas distribuidas en una viga")
        ax.legend()
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cargasvigas = CargasV()
    cargasvigas.plot()
```

### Nota:

Si cabe la  posibilidad de darme una sugerencia para la opimización del código bienvenida sea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que estas utilizando `ax.axis('equal')`, esto hace que la relación de aspecto del eje "X" y el eje "Y" sea igual ([Documentación](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html), [Ejemplos de "equal"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html)). Es por eso que el eje X toma valores tan grandes, para intentar hace que la escala del eje "X" y "Y" visualmente sean iguales.

Comentando esa línea, el código muestra la gráfica utilizando los datos de "X" y "Y" para calcular el rango visual de la gráfica

Si deseas tener un poco más de control del rango que deseas mostrar en el eje "X" puedes utilizar:

```
plt.xlim([-0.5, 5.5])
```

Donde `-0.5` es el límite inferior y `5.5` el límite superior del campo visual de la gráfica para el eje "X"

Ejemplo completo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches


class CargasV():
    
    def diseño_viga_apoyada(self,ax):
        """"
        Esta funcion es la encargada de graficar la viga apoyada en el eje x
        inicialmente la longitud de la viga será de 18 metros, este paramtro 
        se puede modificar en la funcion pasandole un valor numerico
        """
        coordenada_y = 0
        coordenada_x = 0
        vertices = [(coordenada_x,coordenada_y),5,-1.5]
        self.vC = vertices #vertices cuadrado
        ax.add_patch(
            patches.Rectangle(
            self.vC[0],
            self.vC[1],
            self.vC[2],
            fill=False,
            label='viga apoyada',
            color=("black"),
            linewidth=1.8
             ))
        return plt.plot()
    
# -/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-    
    def funciones(self,valor_final_x):

        X = np.linspace(0,valor_final_x,1000) #Le doy un valor de 100o por si es una función con muchas curvas como sen(x)
        Y = X**2
        return plt.plot(X,Y)
            
    def plot(self):
 # -/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/- #Caractericticas inciales del plot -/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-    
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        #ax.axis('equal')
        ax.grid(ls='--', lw=0.6)
        self.diseño_viga_apoyada(ax)
        self.funciones(5)
        plt.yticks(np.arange(0,25,5))
        plt.title("Cargas distribuidas en una viga")
        ax.legend()
        plt.xlim([-0.5, 5.5])
        
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cargasvigas = CargasV()
    cargasvigas.plot()
```

**Nota adicional:** Cambié el ancho de la viga para que pueda verse mejor, originalmente era `-0.25` y lo cambié a `-1.5`

```
vertices = [(coordenada_x,coordenada_y),5,-1.5]
```

Esta es la gráfica resultante:

[image: Gráfica]

Comment: ¡Como no pude pensarlo antes! Muchas gracias por la respuesta eta lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: No hay de qué! Saludos!